# how to filter view for users in yii2?

Tags: authentication, yii2

in my project Logged users access to her view but I want the user can not access to another users with change url.
in this usersController :

```
 [
    'allow' => true,
    'actions' => ['update', 'view'],
    'matchCallback' => function () {
        return ($this->checkAccess(User::ROLE_USER));
     },
 ],
```

and

```
  public function actionView($id)
{
    return $this->render('view', [
        'model' => $this->findModel($id),
    ]);
}
```

if user1 go to : web/users/view@id=1 , he can go to web/users/view@id=2 .

how to prevent from this problem?

Comment: Do you want exactly with this code or any code is fine?

Comment: in this project each user can see his messages. for this the user must go to messages/view&id=3 (msg 3 for user1)and (msg5 for user2). if user1 goto  messages/view&id=5, is seen another message view.

Comment: Seems like you want restrict access to objects to their authors. Check this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39218303/restricting-controller-action-to-creator-of-post-in-yii2), I covered it in depth in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution could be, instead of getting the ID of the user from url, you could get the same ID from session. Something like:

```
public function actionView()
{
    if (!Yii::$app->user->isGuest) { // the user is logged in
        $id = Yii::$app->user->getId(); // get the id

        return $this->render('view', [
            'model' => $this->findModel($id),
        ]);
    }

    throw new NotFoundHttpException('The requested page does not exist.');
}
```

And the url will be `web/users/view` for any user.

Or you can also compare the ID given with the user current ID:

```
public function actionView($id)
{
    if (!Yii::$app->user->isGuest && $id == Yii::$app->user->getId()) {
        return $this->render('view', [
            'model' => $this->findModel($id),
        ]);
    }

    throw new NotFoundHttpException('The requested page does not exist.');
}
```

Comment: your code is true just for user/view No all controllers.

Comment: This solutions will work in any controller. If you have any trouble implementing it, update your question with your Controller and View.